# C++ vector of vector conversion

Tags: c++, vector

I am fairly new to C++ and this might be a dumb question.

If I have 2 vectors,

> `vector<vector< double >> v1` , has values

and

> `const vector<vector< double> * > * v2`,  has no values

.

How would I go about storing the elements from v1 to v2 or would it be possible to cast v1 as

> `const vector<vector< double> * > *`

Comment: one of the stars is not necessary, but anyway you can use std::move

Comment: You cannot cast `v1` that way, as the two types are not compatible. But you can certainly store pointers to `v1`'s elements into `v2`, if that is your intention. Though, declaring `v2` as (a pointer to) a `const` vector will make that job a bit harder as you would have to write a custom conversion function or custom iterator class to initialize the `vector` with.

Comment: This gets you part of the way: ` vector <vector<double>> v1;
 const vector <vector<double>>* v2 = &v1;` ...but it doesn't have the * after vector<double> in v2's definition. You can't do that conversion in just one line of assignment. So: what's the purpose of this code? Do we need the vector<double> to go from vector<double> to vector<double>*?

Comment: Warning: The C-style cast and the `reinterpret_cast` will allow you to perform the conversion and get the code to compile by ordering the compiler to obey your demands, but the result will fail at runtime. Never use a cast just to get code to compile. You need to know what the cast is really doing and how it will solve your problem or you're probably trading a compiler error that you know about for a runtime error that you will have to find the hard way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry I'm a little lost. When you say storing pointers to v1's element into v2, do you mean using using iterator to point to v1's elements then storing the iterator into v2?

Comment: @TopologicalSort Yes I am trying to go from vector<double> to vector<double>*

Comment: @user4581301 I see. I think thats the mistake I was doing earlier. Trying to force conversion via casting while hoping it will fix the compilation error.

Comment: @RD7 I attempted to use std::move initially but it did not work due to incompatible types

Comment: Can you say why? There may be an easier solution than doing that.

...If you are set on this, you can create the vectors, loop through everything in v1, and copy appropriately into v2. It's not a one-line solution, but what you're doing is very unusual, so we shouldn't blame C++ for not making it easy.

Comment: You can point a `vector<double>*` at a `vector<double>`, but you can't do much with a `vector<double*>*` and a `vector<double>` They are storing different things. I think we need a more concrete description of what you want to do. I'd add in a description of why you want to do it, because when you have a problem with a solution to a problem it's beneficial to reexamine the original problem to see if there is a better solution to it.

Comment: @User404 No, I meant exactly what I said. Storing **pointers** not iterators (since you declared `v2` has holding **pointers**), eg `vector<vector< double> * > * v2 = ...; v2->push_back(&v1[0]); v2->push_back(&v1[1]); etc ...` But now you have changed your details, so this no longer applies.  So you need to explain EXACTLY what you are really trying to accomplish, and EXACTLY what problems you are having with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v1` is a vector of vectors, i.e. each element of `v1` is a vector of type `vector<double>`.

`v2` is a pointer to a vector of pointers, that is it points to a vector, which has pointers (to other vectors) as elements.

As you can see, `v1` and `v2` are completely different, in terms of types and binary layout, so no, you cannot cast one to another and have a valid program.

Assuming that with `v2` you want to pass a list of pointers to `v1`, e.g. as a function argument, the way to do this is to construct a vector of pointers, where each element would be a pointer to the corresponding element of `v1`:

```
void foo(const vector<vector<double>*>* v2);

void bar(vector<vector<double>> const& v1)
{
    // Allocate a vector of pointers
    vector<vector<double>*> vp(v1.size(), nullptr);

    // Initialize the pointers to point to v1 elements
    for (std::size_t i = 0u, n = v1.size(); i < n; ++i)
    {
        vp[i] = &v1[i];
    }

    // Pass the pointer to the vector of pointers to your destination
    foo(&vp);
}
```

It should be noted that this code is not cheap as it will have to allocate dynamic memory and initialize the vector of pointers. If your goal was to save performance on copying the data, you should pass a reference to the original vector instead (i.e. `vector<vector<double>> const&`).

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. This is exactly what I needed